# How to use NOT operator (^) in regular expression pattern of XSLT?

Tags: regex, xslt, xml-parsing

I want to write an XSLT function which should substitute all the characters except below:

```
0-9A-Za-z_ * & . , #
```

So, I wrote a regular expression pattern in below function:

```
<xsl:function name="wd:allowed_characters">
        <xsl:param name="input_param" />
        <xsl:if test="$input_param !=' '" >
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(replace($input_param,'^[a-zA-Z0-9_ * & . , #]',''))" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:function>
```

Looks like, Not operator (^) is not working as other languages.
Can you suggest me about where am I doing wrong? How can I achieve my goal here?

Correct Function is below:

```
 <xsl:function name="wd:allowed_characters">
        <xsl:param name="input_param" />
        <xsl:if test="$input_param !=' '" >
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(replace($input_param,'[^.#, \- _ * a-zA-Z0-9]',''))" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:function>
```

Comment: Why is `-` added and `&` went missing in your "correct function"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `^` inside the square brackets `replace($input_param,'[^a-zA-Z0-9_ * & . , #]','')`, but you could also simply use `translate($input_param, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0-9_ * & . , #', '')`.

Comment: Thank you @Martin. It helped me in correcting my function and it worked. I updated the correct function in my question.